# How should I schedule some simple delayed tasks in Scala?

Tags: scala, scheduling

I'm making a [Chaos Monkey](http://techblog.netflix.com/2010/12/5-lessons-weve-learned-using-aws.html) program and I want it to clean up after itself after a certain period of time. I'd like a simple way to queue up cleanup tasks to be called a set amount of time in the future. I think I could do something with actors and a lot of hand-waving but that seems like the wrong approach. Is there a better tool for this task in the Scala standard library?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6227759/132374

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have written a scheduling DSL in Scala called [**foil**](https://github.com/oxbowlakes/foil), which is freely available on Github. It will work with either of Java Calendar/Date, or the Joda library. The syntax looks like this:

```
schedule(f) now
schedule(f) onceAfter 5.minutes
schedule(f) onceAt inst
schedule(f) onceAtNext time
schedule(f) todayNoEarlierThan time
```

Where f is a closure (i.e. `() => Unit`). There's many more examples [on the Wiki](https://github.com/oxbowlakes/foil/wiki) and an [example REPL session](https://github.com/oxbowlakes/foil/wiki/5-minutes-of-your-attention) with foil, showing how to use it (with both Java Date/Calendar and JODA).

Comment: Looks awesome and just what I need. Since I have your attention here: Is there some way to stop a scheduled task if I'm shutting down my program? And perhaps immediately run it before shutdown? Also, this there some way to add jitter to my scheduling (`schedule(f) now andThenEvery 2 to 100 minutes` or so)?

Comment: You can add a *shutdown hook*, which is part of the JDK (`Runtime.addShutdownHook`), or create your underlying scheduler as using daemon threads. For your last question, the answer is "no" because a `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` is used under the covers. By all means, this could be added via a separate pimp, though! Let me know if you are serious about using this and I'll look to add the code to foil

Comment: I'd like to use it but, frankly, all the local dependencies and the like are getting to be a pain...

Comment: Then "steal" the source code :-) The deps on saturn and JODA are *only* if you wish to use these at runtime. They are not required to use the library

Answer (score 4):

There's not *so* much hand waving involved, `reactWithin` combined with the `TIMEOUT` message will let you do this.

You can also use `Futures.alarm` to create a waitable `Future` that will resolve after the specified time limit.

Comment: Both sound interesting and aren't things I know anything back. Might you have some links to introductions to them? Thanks.

Comment: The Scaladoc is fairly good for these but, having just read the Wiki, I think you'd be much better off with Chris's Foil library.